# Documentation for Pictures and Picture Methods and Properties with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am starting to work on a very old workbook that makes extensive use of the `Pictures` and `Picture` Objects.  These Objects are "Hidden" in my version of Excel *(2007)*.  I can "Un-hide" them in the Object Browser like:

[image]

I would now like to "un-hide" the documentation material in *VBA Help*, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Does anyone know how to get VBA Help to display this material ??
or
Is anyone aware of similar documentation material availabe online ??

Comment: Which library is the `Picture` type located in?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Appears to be in the Excel Library.

Comment: Huh, it appears to be an undocumented type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the interop section of MSDN:
The [Pictures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pictures.aspx) and [Picture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.picture.aspx) classes.